# How combine column information into one row in ms SQL Server Management 2005

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to combine multiple rows into one row.

Example

```
Office 1    NULL    NULL    12/15/2020
Office 1    NULL    10/15/2008  NULL
Office 1    1949885 NULL        NULL
```

I'm using an inner join with case statements to query the information. I just can't figure how combine all the data into one row

I want my outcome to be this

```
Office 1  1949885 10/15/2008 12/15/2020
```

Here's my query

```
select distinct GroupName, (case when userid=1 then data end) as TPI,
    (case when userid=4 then data end) as Enrollment_Date,
    (case when userid=19 then data end) as Expiration_Date
    from offices
    inner join userdefinedoff uo on uo.OfficeID=Offices.OfficeID
    where userid=1 or userid=4 or userid=19
```

All the number data is stored as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
office1column,
max(Col1),
max(COl2)
..
from
table
group by office1column
```

max/min will ignore  nulls in a group and gives  you the value if present

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: @ryanb082:glad it helped..i recommend to take a look at this link ,so that it will help you in how to ask future questions and you will also get upvotes :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/